# RunSnakeRun does not open at all on windows

Tags: python, profile

I'm trying to use runsnakerun to visualize some profile made with cProfile, but I'm not able to open it.
I tried to open my file with :

```
C:\Users\Maxime\PycharmProjects\NMMSofware>c:\Anaconda2\Scripts\runsnake.exe o.prof
```

or

```
C:\Anaconda2\Scripts>runsnake.exe
```

I also tried to run it from the Scripts folder by doubleclick on runsnake.exe application but nothing append.

I tried to reinstall it without success.

I'm out of idea.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and couldn't find a solution. I think it's because of wxpython version incompatibility. In the end, I found [snakeviz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/) and I was able to visualize my profile data.

Comment: I would like to thank you very much, Carl from the past, for sharing this tool!